# How to emit state from a stream?

Tags: flutter, bloc, state-management, flutter-bloc, supabase-flutter

Im learning flutter bloc. im trying to make a authentication event work.

This is my bloc

```
class SplashBloc extends Bloc<SplashEvent, SplashState> {
  final supabaseClient = Supabase.instance.client;
  StreamSubscription<AuthState>? _subscription;
  Session? userSession;
  SplashBloc() : super(SplashInitialState()) {
    on<SplashInitialEvent>(
      (event, emit) {
        // listenAuthState(event, emit);
      },
    );
  }
  @override
  Stream<SplashState> mapEventToState(SplashEvent event,) async* {
    _subscription?.cancel();
    if (event is SplashInitialEvent) {
            _subscription = supabaseClient.auth.onAuthStateChange.listen((event) {
        if (event.session?.accessToken != null) {
          emit(SignedInState()); // The member 'emit' can only be used within 'package:bloc/src/bloc.dart' or a test.
        } else {
          yield NotSignedInState(); //Yield statements must be in a generator function (one marked with either 'async*' or 'sync*').Try adding 'async*' or 'sync*' to the enclosing function.
        }
      });
    }
   }
```

What is the correct way to listen to a stream and update the state? I'm still figuring bloc any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`mapEventToState` was removed from flutter_bloc years ago. I'm pretty sure you're seeing a warning about `invalid override` or something. Its definitely the reason you're seeing those other errors.

If you're in line with the up to date version of flutter bloc, then you usually don't have to manually create `StreamSubscriptions`. You can utilize `emit.forEach`.

There's some good reading about this [here](https://verygood.ventures/blog/how-to-use-bloc-with-streams-and-concurrency)

This should be a mostly or fully working example based on what you provided.

```
class SplashInitListener extends SplashEvent {} // fire this whenever you want to init the listener, probably on app start

class SplashBloc extends Bloc<SplashEvent, SplashState> {
  final supabaseClient = Supabase.instance.client;
  // StreamSubscription<AuthState>? _subscription; // don't need this
  Session? userSession; // not sure you need this either, definitely not for the example below 
  SplashBloc() : super(SplashInitialState()) {
    on<SplashInitListener>(_onSplashInitListener);
  }

  Future<void> _onSplashInitListener(
    SplashInitListener event,
    Emitter<SplashState> emit,
  ) async {
    // emit.forEach takes a stream and returns a new state when the stream
    // is updated
    emit.forEach<AuthState>(
      supabaseClient.auth.onAuthStateChange, // stream from Supabase
      // The state returned from the onData callback is what is emitted and all listeners will be notified
      onData: (AuthState authState) {
        if (authState.session?.accessToken != null) {
          return SignedInState();
        } else {
          return NotSignedInState();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

That should do it for 'ya